# Defining dependencies between .dll in NuGet packages

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I have defined a nuget nuspec file similar to the following:

```
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
<metadata>
    <id></id>
    <version></version>
    <title></title>
    <authors></authors>
    <owners />
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description></description>
    <references>
        <reference file="A.dll" />
    </references>
</metadata>
<files>
    <file src="A.dll" target="lib\net40-client" />
    <file src="B.dll" target="lib\net40-client" />
</files>
```

this ensures that B.dll is copied alongside A.dll when the project is built without adding B.dll as a reference.

Now suppose B.dll depends on C.dll, how do I construct the nuspec files for A.dll and B.dll to express this dependency, so that both B.dll and C.dll will be copied alongside A.dll without adding either B.dll or C.dll as a reference or explicitly adding C.dll in the nuspec file for A.dll.

Answer (score 1):

If B.dll requires C.dll, then it ought to be included in your `<files>` list.  I don't know how you can get around that.

```
<files>
 <file src="A.dll" target="lib\net40-client" />
 <file src="B.dll" target="lib\net40-client" />
 <file src="C.dll" target="lib\net40-client" />
</files>
```

Per the [Nuspec documentation](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference) for  `references`: *Names of assemblies under lib that are added as project references. If unspecified, all references in lib are added as project references. When specifying a reference, only specify the name and not the path inside the package.*

Thus, by specifying `A.dll` as the only `reference`, NuGet knows to not add a project reference to `C.dll`.